# Solving the Traveling Salesman Problem with bruteforce

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

For a school project, I am trying to implement a bruteforce algorithm to the Traveling Salesman Problem. What I would like to do is, that I enter an integer which represents the number of points, for each point there will given an random x and y value which represents their position on a 2D Plane. After all points have been initialized, the algorithm will calculate the distance for each route starting from point 1 and then permutate all different possibilites.

Update 1:

So I coded the Point.java and the PointManager.java classes which there purpose is to initialize the points and keep them in an arraylist.
They look like this
Point.java:

```
public class Point {

    int x;
    int y;

    //Constructs a random Point
    public Point(){
        this.x = (int)(Math.random()*200);
        this.y = (int)(Math.random()*200);
    }

    //gives Point X Position
    public int getPosX(){
        return this.x;
    }

    //gives Point Y Position
    public int getPosY(){
        return this.y;
    }

    public double distance(Point point){
        int distance_x = Math.abs(getPosX() - point.getPosX());
        int distance_y = Math.abs(getPosY() - point.getPosY());
        double distance = Math.sqrt((distance_x * distance_x) + (distance_y * distance_y));
        return distance;
    }  
}
```

PointManager.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class PointManager {

    // Holds our cities
    private static ArrayList destinationPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();

    // Adds a destination city
    public static void addPoint(Point point) {
        destinationPoints.add(point);
    }

    // Get a city
    public static Point getPoint(int index){
        return (Point)destinationPoints.get(index);
    }

    // Get the number of destination cities
    public static int numberOfPoints(){
        return destinationPoints.size();
    } 
}
```

Now my question is, how would I continue doing the different permutations of the possibilities and how do I check if a point has already been used in a route?

Comment: So what is your problem here?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is a Question-and-Answer platform. What is your question?

Comment: Although I've voted for reopening the question, I strongly suggest you to suggest at least some approach of yours and point what are the problems with it

Comment: Yea, that what I am currently doing, this was meant for some general adivice in the beginning and when I am come in a problem or need adivce. Btw this is my first time using stackoverflow so I dont know if this is allowed. I will keep this updated when I make progress

Comment: Unless you are obliged to code your own Point, I would suggest to use the built in type. There is no point in re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution uses recursion:

It keeps track of which points are visited, and which still need to be visited.
At every invocation, it simply extends the current path with all possible 'next points'.

Whenever there are no more points to include, it prints the path.

```
private static void branch(Set<Point> todoPoints, List<Point> donePoints){
    if(todoPoints.isEmpty()){
        // measure distance
        double totalDistance = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < donePoints.size(); i++) {
            totalDistance += donePoints.get(i).distance(donePoints.get((i+1) % donePoints.size()));
        }
        System.out.println("Solution found");
        System.out.println("\t" + donePoints);
        System.out.println("\t"+totalDistance);
    }else{
        for(Point nextPoint : todoPoints){
            // add point
            donePoints.add(nextPoint);

            // recurse
            Set<Point> tmp = new HashSet<>(todoPoints);
            tmp.remove(nextPoint);
            branch(tmp, donePoints);

            // remove point
            donePoints.remove(nextPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this strategy can be improved upon.
We could keep track of the current minimal distance, and use this.
There is -for instance- no added value in extending a path that is already above the current minimal distance.

That would look like this:

```
private static void branch2(Set<Point> todoPoints, List<Point> donePoints, double dist){
    if(todoPoints.isEmpty()){
        dist += donePoints.get(0).distance(donePoints.get(donePoints.size()-1));
        CURRENT_MIN_DIST = java.lang.Math.min(CURRENT_MIN_DIST, dist);
        System.out.println("Solution found");
        System.out.println("\t" + donePoints);
        System.out.println("\t"+dist);
    }else{
        for(Point nextPoint : todoPoints){
            // add point
            donePoints.add(nextPoint);

            // update distance
            dist += (donePoints.size() > 1 ? donePoints.get(donePoints.size()-2).distance(donePoints.get(donePoints.size()-1)) : 0);

            // we do not recurse if the current distance is already bigger than a known minimum
            if(dist > CURRENT_MIN_DIST)
                continue;

            // recurse
            Set<Point> tmp = new HashSet<>(todoPoints);
            tmp.remove(nextPoint);
            branch2(tmp, donePoints, dist);

            // remove point
            donePoints.remove(nextPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, a further improvement would be to keep track of the minimal distance you would need to add in order to finish the current path.

Then you can prune this recursion even further.
You could check

> current distance + minimal required distance to finish < current min distance

That could be implemented like this:

```
private static void branch3(Set<Point> todoPoints, List<Point> donePoints, double dist){
    if(todoPoints.isEmpty()){
        dist += donePoints.get(0).distance(donePoints.get(donePoints.size()-1));
        CURRENT_MIN_DIST = java.lang.Math.min(CURRENT_MIN_DIST, dist);
        System.out.println("Solution found");
        System.out.println("\t" + donePoints);
        System.out.println("\t"+dist);
    }else{
        for(Point nextPoint : todoPoints){
            // add point
            donePoints.add(nextPoint);

            // update distance
            dist += (donePoints.size() > 1 ? donePoints.get(donePoints.size()-2).distance(donePoints.get(donePoints.size()-1)) : 0);

            // we do not recurse if the current distance is already bigger than a known minimum
            if(dist > CURRENT_MIN_DIST)
                continue;

            if(dist + minDistToFinish(todoPoints) > CURRENT_MIN_DIST)
                continue;

            // recurse
            Set<Point> tmp = new HashSet<>(todoPoints);
            tmp.remove(nextPoint);
            branch3(tmp, donePoints, dist);

            // remove point
            donePoints.remove(nextPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

With the relevant method looking like this:

```
private static double minDistToFinish(Set<Point> todoPoints){
    double distToFinish = 0;
    for(Point p1 : todoPoints){
        double d = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for(Point p2 : todoPoints){
            if(p1.equals(p2))
                continue;
            d = java.lang.Math.min(d, p1.distance(p2));
        }
        distToFinish += d;
    }
    return distToFinish;
}
```